# How to define a slot of another template type in jess

Tags: java, jess

I have a template called Person, and this template has eyes, hands, body, and alot of other slots. But each one of these slots are other templates.
So how can I define a slot for template of other template type??
And how to define the facts ??

Here is an example of what I main:

```
(deftemplate Eyes
(slot colorOfEye (type STRING))
(slot ShapeOfEye (type STRING)))
(deftemplate Person 
(slot eye (type Eyes))
)
(deffacts People
(Person (eye ....))
)
(reset)
```

defining Person template is not working like this, and I don't know how to define the facts

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define them both as separate templates. Then you can store either `fact-id` or some other identifier for the "sub-fact" in the main fact, then join the main fact pattern with a "sub-fact" pattern using that value:

```
(defrule blue-eyed-person
    (person (name ?name) (eyes ?eyes))
    ?eyes <- (eyes (color blue))
    =>
    (printout t ?name " has blue eyes." crlf))
```

Or alternatively

```
(defrule blue-eyed-person
    (person (name ?name) (eyes ?eyes))
    (eyes (id ?eyes) (color blue))
    =>
    (printout t ?name " has blue eyes." crlf))
```

To create the facts in the first place, you might say

```
(bind ?eyes (assert (eyes (color blue))))
(assert (person (name Fred) (eyes ?eyes)))
```

Comment: But I didn't understand how to define the person template's slots (it's not working to set the type to Eyes) ?? 
and how to define the facts about person?

Comment: Slot type exists only for compatibility with CLIPS; it is not used for anything in Jess. Just don't fill it in. I'll edit my answer to show how to assert the facts.

Comment: Thanks alot, but I just want to know if it's the only way to do it right? I can't do it without asserting facts about eyes?

Comment: That's correct. Slots can't have any structure of their own (they can be multislots -- i.e., list-containing slots -- but that's it.) If you want one slot to contain structured information, then it should refer to another fact... OR a Java object. You can have Person, Eye, Hand, Body Java classes, and use "defclass" to map them into Jess.